# Name Of This Outer-Garment and It's Relevance To Sunnah

Tags: clothing

I've seen many scholars (from different school of thoughts like sunni, shia, nakshbandi etc) wearing this overcoat/cloak like garment. I would like to know:

- What is the correct name of this garment in Arabic and English language?
- Is it Sunnah to wear this? Since scholars from different school of thought wear this so I believe that it must be Sunnah.
- It looks very modest. Can I wear it daily?

**Images**

The outer gray garment (looks like an overcoat/cloak)

[image]

The outer skin color garment (looks like an overcoat/cloak)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **too broad**. Stick to 1 question.